# Excel count Unique ID's between two dates + a distinct count of another column for each ID

Tags: excel, unique

I am struggling with an Excel formula. I am trying to count the number of Unique ID's between two dates (I have that formula working), but I also want to count the SignUpRoles for each unique ID that qualified between the two dates. I am using O365.

Here is how I am capturing the UserId counts in K10:14

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(Weartime13[RecordDate]>=K5,IF(Weartime13[RecordDate]<=J5,MATCH(Weartime13[UserId],Weartime13[UserId],0))),ROW(Weartime13[UserId])-ROW(A5)+1),1))
```

Here is the worksheet I am working with: [RDS_Report](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Av_T_1LX0-awgq0kVw_Lu5GI8JrTrg?e=RRTUUQ)

Screenshot:
[RDS Report Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15wrl.png)

Comment: I reformatted this question and provided a worksheet link in an attempt to communicate my challenge a little better. This is an Excel task that got handed to me from a work colleague and I am not really that strong with Excel. So, I appreciate any guidance ;-)

Comment: I'm not clear about the question - it looks from the data as though there is exactly one type of SignUpRole per userID? If it's the total number of unique ID's for a particular type of SignUpRole that you need, can't you just add another 'If' to your formula, or alternatively (as you have O365) use filter and unique? It would be clearer if you could fill in the expected results for your sample data.

Comment: Hi @TomSharpe thanks for the reply. Sorry for any confusion. I'll try to explain a little better. Basically, there are 7 unique userid's in the sample worksheet. If 4 unique ID's qualify between the date ranges, of those 4 userID's:  2 Are Parent Only and 2 are Brace Wearer Signup roles. -- I updated the worksheet with the sample data. Thanks!

Comment: OK - I was still a bit confused because the dates in J5:O5 changed since I took a copy of your sample sheet and I got different answers from you. That makes sense now but I think the screenshot might need changing to match.

Comment: @TomSharpe This was a great exercise in learning for me. Appreciate your kind assistance and directions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I mean by adding another 'if' is that in L14 (for example) you would have

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(Weartime13[RecordDate]>=O5,IF(Weartime13[RecordDate]<=J5,IF(Weartime13[SignUpRole]=L9,MATCH(Weartime13[UserId],Weartime13[UserId],0)))),ROW(Weartime13[UserId])-ROW(A5)+1),1))
```

and in the next column that would change to M9 and N9:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(Weartime13[RecordDate]>=O5,IF(Weartime13[RecordDate]<=J5,IF(Weartime13[SignUpRole]=M9,MATCH(Weartime13[UserId],Weartime13[UserId],0)))),ROW(Weartime13[UserId])-ROW(A5)+1),1))

=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(Weartime13[RecordDate]>=O5,IF(Weartime13[RecordDate]<=J5,IF(Weartime13[SignUpRole]=N9,MATCH(Weartime13[UserId],Weartime13[UserId],0)))),ROW(Weartime13[UserId])-ROW(A5)+1),1))
```

I've filled in the last row:

[image]

**EDIT**

As noted by @JosWoolley, a structured reference would have been preferable to row(A5). I would suggest:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(Weartime13[RecordDate]>=O5,IF(Weartime13[RecordDate]<=J5,IF(Weartime13[SignUpRole]=L9,MATCH(Weartime13[UserId],Weartime13[UserId],0)))),ROW(Weartime13[UserId])-ROW(Weartime13[#Headers])),1))
```

But what if you want to pull these formulas across so that L9 changes automatically to M9 and N9 but it still references the same table columns? I had to look this one up and the answer is:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(Weartime13[[RecordDate]:[RecordDate]]>=$O5,IF(Weartime13[[RecordDate]:[RecordDate]]<=$J5,IF(Weartime13[[SignUpRole]:[SignUpRole]]=L9,MATCH(Weartime13[[UserId]:[UserId]],Weartime13[[UserId]:[UserId]],0)))),ROW(Weartime13[[UserId]:[UserId]])-ROW(Weartime13[#Headers])),1))
```

Formula for the last row using count & filter would be

```
=COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER(Weartime13[UserId],(Weartime13[RecordDate]<=J5)*(Weartime13[RecordDate]>=O5))))
```

for the total and

```
=COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER(Weartime13[[UserId]:[UserId]],(Weartime13[[RecordDate]:[RecordDate]]<=$J5)*(Weartime13[[RecordDate]:[RecordDate]]>=$O5)*(Weartime13[[SignUpRole]:[SignUpRole]]=L9))))
```

pulled across for the SignUpRole breakdown, assuming UserId is numeric.

But what if you wanted a single formula that could be pulled both down and across for the whole range of dates and roles? This could be arranged as follows:

```
=COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER(Weartime13[UserId],(Weartime13[RecordDate]<=J$5)*(Weartime13[RecordDate]>=INDEX($K$5:$O$5,ROW()-ROW($9:$9))))))
```

for the total and

```
=COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER(Weartime13[[UserId]:[UserId]],(Weartime13[[RecordDate]:[RecordDate]]<=$J$5)*(Weartime13[[RecordDate]:[RecordDate]]>=INDEX($K$5:$O$5,ROW()-ROW($9:$9)))*(Weartime13[[SignUpRole]:[SignUpRole]]=L$9))))
```

for the role columns.

Is there a simpler way of doing this whole thing? Maybe with pivot tables or perhaps power query, but that would be a separate answer :-)

Comment: I know that you've copied it from the OP's original formula, though it's preferable not to reference Excel tables using non-structured references to the cells within those tables, so I would replace `ROW(A5)` with `ROW(INDEX(Weartime13[UserId],1))`

Comment: @JosWoolley Thanks, I will go an update my master workbook with that suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @JosWoolley, good point. If I have time I will improve my answer and put in a filter/unique alternative, of course feel free to add an answer of your own.